# How to display hitboxes in game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, displayobject

I want to display the hitboxes of my character in game with a debug mod.
Is it possible to do so ? How to display them ?

It's a 3d game with different shapes of colliders.
Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: Is it a box collider ? is it  a 2D game or a 3D game ?

Comment: Please share, how you have set up your character. If it's 2D or 3D. And what kind of collider you've used for the hitboxes

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use the [OnDrawGizmos()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html) method to draw different of shapes.

To create a visuallization of your hitbox you can also combine the [Gizmos.DrawCube](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawCube.html)
 to create a 3D box and define it's position which will be the center of your character and it's size which will be the same as your collider size.

Here is an example directly from Unity's documentation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // Draw a green box at the transform's position
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawCube(transform.position, new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
    }
}
```

If you want to make this more dynamic, you get a reference of your box collider and directly use it's size instead of adding it manually for each time, like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BoxCollider collider;
    
    void Awake()
    {
        collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }
    
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // Draw a green box at the transform's position
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawCube(transform.position, collider.size);
    }
}
```

**Updated Version** to work at runtime using [Debug.DrawLine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html)

```
public Color boxColor = Color.green;

void DrawHitBox()
{
    Vector3 boxPosition = boxCollider.transform.position + boxCollider.center;
    Vector3 boxSize = boxCollider.size;

    Vector3 point1 = boxPosition + new Vector3(-boxSize.x, -boxSize.y, -boxSize.z) * 0.5f;
    Vector3 point2 = boxPosition + new Vector3(-boxSize.x, -boxSize.y, boxSize.z) * 0.5f;
    Vector3 point3 = boxPosition + new Vector3(boxSize.x, -boxSize.y, boxSize.z) * 0.5f;
    Vector3 point4 = boxPosition + new Vector3(boxSize.x, -boxSize.y, -boxSize.z) * 0.5f;

    Vector3 point5 = boxPosition + new Vector3(-boxSize.x, boxSize.y, -boxSize.z) * 0.5f;
    Vector3 point6 = boxPosition + new Vector3(-boxSize.x, boxSize.y, boxSize.z) * 0.5f;
    Vector3 point7 = boxPosition + new Vector3(boxSize.x, boxSize.y, boxSize.z) * 0.5f;
    Vector3 point8 = boxPosition + new Vector3(boxSize.x, boxSize.y, -boxSize.z) * 0.5f;

    Debug.DrawLine(point1, point2, boxColor);
    Debug.DrawLine(point2, point3, boxColor);
    Debug.DrawLine(point3, point4, boxColor);
    Debug.DrawLine(point4, point1, boxColor);

    Debug.DrawLine(point5, point6, boxColor);
    Debug.DrawLine(point6, point7, boxColor);
    Debug.DrawLine(point7, point8, boxColor);
    Debug.DrawLine(point8, point5, boxColor);

    Debug.DrawLine(point1, point5, boxColor);
    Debug.DrawLine(point2, point6, boxColor);
    Debug.DrawLine(point3, point7, boxColor);
    Debug.DrawLine(point4, point8, boxColor);
}

void Update()
{
    DrawHitBox();
}
```

Comment: thx, but in the doc, we can reed that Gizmos are used to give visual debugging or setup aids in the Scene view and not in the game view

Comment: Yes, you are correct let me update my answer by using the "Debug.DrawLine()" method

Comment: Debug.DrawLine() also only shows in the scene window.

Comment: @RocketmanDan You need to enable the Gizmos inside the GameVIew in order to see it. You can find the option on the top-right side of the GameVIew.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to simply use the Physics Debug Visualization to show the colliders of your GameObjects in the Scene view. To open this, open the window: Window > Analysis > Physics Debugger

More information can be found here on the Unity manual: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsDebugVisualization.html

Comment: Thank you but I think that it only shows the colliders in the scene view and not the game view